# ReactJS - error on maximum update depth exceeded despite conditional check

Tags: reactjs

After I included the code below in my componentDidUpdate() method I started to get "Error: Maximum update depth exceeded.". My goal is to filter the array 'appointmentsByMonth' every time the selectedDate gets updated and set the state with the resulted value. What am I doing wrong? I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

```
    componentDidUpdate = (prevState) => {
      const { selectedDate } = this.state;
      const { appointmentsByMonth } = this.props;

      if (selectedDate !== prevState.selectedDate) {
        this.setState({visibleAppointments: appointmentsByMonth.filter(apt => moment(apt.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD') === moment(selectedDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))})
    }
}
```

Comment: Issue is that you are updating the state inside a condition that turns out to be true every time and it results in infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for `componentDidUpdate` is:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {}
```

`prevState` is the second positional argument and in your case you're using `prevProps`.

```
componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
      const { selectedDate } = this.state;
      const { appointmentsByMonth } = this.props;

      if (selectedDate !== prevState.selectedDate) {
        this.setState({visibleAppointments: appointmentsByMonth.filter(apt => moment(apt.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD') === moment(selectedDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))})
    }
```